How can I reuse a field from a Yup schema?
Say I have a schema like below:
export const schema = yup.object({
  id: yup.number().label("ID").positive().integer().required(),
  name: yup.string().label("name").max(255).required()
});

How can I reuse and change the name property so it's notRequired()? I thought I could do this via yup.reach(schema, "name").notRequired(), but I get TS errors in my IDE that

Property 'notRequired' does not exist on type 'Reference | ISchema<string, AnyObject, any, any>'. Property 'notRequired' does not exist on type 'Reference'.


You can use this code to solve Ts error:


(yup.reach(schema, 'name') as yup.Schema).notRequired()




This breaks the type inference, unfortunately.
